# AVD only works for me when I run the intel HAXM installer and it fails

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

Basically I installed Android Studio and I tried to run the AVD and it failed, I enabled IVT in the bios and I checked to see if I had disabled Hyper-V, which I couldn't find in the windows features so I just left it at that.

After this I navigated to where I had downloaded HAXM and ran the installer but it failed and said VT-x is not enabled, I double checked in bios to see if IVT was enabled and rebooted twice and still got stuck and said Vt-x was not enabled.

I ran the AVD at this point and it worked, however when I exit the installer as it is stuck in this state the AVD stops working, this is shown in the puush link below. How can I 
solve this?

http://puu.sh/lscbH/56779c6945.jpg

I am running Windows 7 Home premium.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to access your computer’s low-level setup screen. On PCs made prior to Windows 8, this is probably a BIOS. On PCs made after Windows 8 came out, this is probably UEFI firmware.

On a BIOS-based system, you’ll need to reboot your comptuer and press the appropriate key while it’s booting to access the BIOS setup screen. For example, this is often the “Delete” or “F2” key. It may also be “Esc”, “F1”, or another key.

You may see a message like “Press [Key} to access setup” on your computer’s screen while it boots. Perform a web search for your computer’s model number and “access BIOS” or examine your computer’s manual if you can’t find the key that works.

Either way, once you’re in, you can begin looking around for an Intel VT-x option.

Typically, you’ll find this option under the Processor submenu. That menu may be located somewhere under “Chipset,” “Northbridge,” “Advanced Chipset Control,” or “Advanced CPU Configuration.”

Look for an option named “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,” or something similar. Enable the option and select “Save and Exit” or the equivalent feature to save your settings changes and reboot your computer.